# Java: Weirdness in replaceAll RegEx

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to manipulate a String in Java to recognize the [markdown options in Facebook Messenger](https://www.facebook.com/help/147348452522644).

I tested the RegEx in a couple of online testers and it worked, but when I tried to implement in Java, it's only recognizing text surrounded by underscores. I have an example that shows the problem here:

````
    private String process(String input) {
        String processed = input.replaceAll("(\\b|^)\\_(.*)\\_(\\b|$)", "underscore")
            .replaceAll("(\\b|^)\\*(.*)\\*(\\b|$)", "star")
            .replaceAll("(\\b|^)```(.*)```(\b|$)", "backticks")
            .replaceAll("(\\b|^)\\~(.*)\\~(\\b|$)", "tilde")
            .replaceAll("(\\b|^)\\`(.*)\\`(\\b|$)", "tick")
            .replaceAll("(\\b|^)\\\\\\((.*)\\\\\\)(\\b|$)", "backslashparen")
            .replaceAll("\\*", "%");  // am I matching stars wrong?

    return processed;
}


public void test() {
    String example = "_Text_\n" +
            "*text*\n" +
            "~Text~\n" +
            "`Text`\n" +
            "_Text_\n" +     // is it only matching the first one?
            "``` Text ```\n" +
            "\\(Text\\)\n" +
            "~Text~\n";
    System.out.println(process(example));
}
````

I expect all the lines would match and be replaced, but only the first line was matched. I wondered if it was because it was the first line, so I copied it in the middle and it matched both. Then I figured I might have missed something matching the special characters, so I added the snip to match the astericks and replace with a percent sign and it worked. The output I'm getting is like so:

````
underscore
%text%
~Text~
`Text`
underscore
``` Text ```
\(Text\)
~Text~
````

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Prefix all your regex with `(?m)` to enable `MULTILINE` match.

Comment: So I used your suggestion and it works as I intend, so thanks. but what I don't understand is that the very first one (underlines) matches at the beginning and in the middle. Can you point me to a reference why this works?  Thanks again!

Comment: Doesnt make sense to use any boundry. Try take out both ^$ and \b. And not use \B becuas if accept `a(` shuld acaept `a_` don't be control by boundry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using word boundaries then there is no need to match anchors in alternation because word boundary also matches start and end positions. So this are actually redundant matches:

```
(?:^|\b)
(?:\b|$)
```

and both can be just be replaced by `\b`.

However looking at your regex please note that only underscore is considered a word character and `*`, `~`, `` ` `` are not word characters hence `\b` cannot be used around those characters instead `\B` should be used which is inverse of `\b`.

Besides this some more improvements can be done like using a negated character class instead of greedy `.*` and removing unnecessary group.

Code:

````
class MyRegex {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String example = "_Text_\n" +
                "*text*\n" +
                "~Text~\n" +
                "`Text`\n" +
                "_Text_\n" +     // is it only matching the first one?
                "``` Text ```\n" +
                "\\(Text\\)\n" +
                "~Text~\n";
        System.out.println(process(example));
    }

    private static String process(String input) {
        String processed = input.replaceAll("\\b_[^_]+_\\b", "underscore")
            .replaceAll("\\B\\*[^*]+\\*\\B", "star")
            .replaceAll("\\B```.+?```\\B", "backticks")
            .replaceAll("\\B~[^~]+~\\B", "tilde")
            .replaceAll("\\B`[^`]+`\\B", "tick")
            .replaceAll("\\B\\\\\\(.*?\\\\\\)\\B", "backslashparen");

        return processed;
    }
}
````

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/DP2aT8)

Comment: Clearly you're way better on the regex nuances than me. Thanks for the assist! Quick question, what are the question marks for? Wouldn't .*? be redundant? (and wouldn't .+? be the same as .*  ? (<-- that is the end of my question, not part of the regex ....). Thanks again.

Comment: `.+?` is slightly more efficient that `.+` because of lazy or non-greedy matcher and if you don't want to match empty string then `.+?` will be more efficient than `.*?`